# Plotting Level 2 NEXRAD Radar Data in Python - TypeError: 'MaskedArray' object is not callable

Tags: python, arrays, matplotlib, netcdf

Hello StackOverflow Community,

I am a novice Python programmer (Python 3.8.1) who is looking for some assistance in plotting NEXRAD level 2 radar imagery that I have exported from the NOAA Weather and Climate Toolkit (gridded NetCDF3 file I believe) on top of a basemap I have created using basemap 1.2.1. I am running my code using Jupyter Notebooks through miniconda on my terminal window (Mac OS Mojave 10.14.6).

Here is the first portion of my code which defines the basemap and successfully plots it along with the coastlines and latitude/longitude lines (note that coordinates for basemap declaration bound the plot to Southern California).

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl

def data_map():
    plt.clf()
    fig = plt.figure(figsize = (10,10))
#----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    #Set lat/lon coordinates for basemap projection (default projection = cylindrical equadistant)
    lllon = -121
    lllat = 32
    urlon = -115.5
    urlat = 35.5

    #set lat/lon coordinates as well as plotting interval for drawing lat/lon as axis of plot
    latmin=32
    latmax=36
    lonmin=-121
    lonmax=-114
    latinterval=1
    loninterval=1
#----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    #create basemap and add some content to create a good starting point for plotting data
    map = Basemap(llcrnrlon=lllon, llcrnrlat=lllat, urcrnrlon=urlon, urcrnrlat=urlat, resolution='f',epsg=3311)
    map.drawcoastlines(linewidth=2,zorder=1)
    map.drawparallels(np.arange(latmin, latmax, latinterval), labels=[1,0,0,0],color='w',textcolor='k',linewidth = 0, zorder=1, fontsize=14)
    map.drawmeridians(np.arange(lonmin, lonmax, loninterval), labels=[0,0,0,1],color='w',textcolor='k',linewidth = 0, zorder=1, fontsize=14)
    map.arcgisimage(service='ESRI_Imagery_World_2D', xpixels=1000)
```

Now here is the second section of my code which is meant to read in the gridded NetCDF3 NEXRAD file that I exported from the NOAA Weather & Climate toolkit (note: file has only one timestep). The code stops before any plotting takes place.

```
import netCDF4 as nc4
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#NEXRAD lvl 2 plotting using NetCDF file
#Read in NetCDF file variables: lat, lon, time, reflect. 
nc_file = nc4.Dataset('/Users/mariandob/Desktop/my-notebook/KNKX_V03_20120325_232219.nc', format='NETCDF3_CLASSIC')
nc_lat  = nc_file.variables['lat'][:]
nc_lon  = nc_file.variables['lon'][:]
nc_time = nc_file.variables['time'][:]
nc_reflect = nc_file.variables['Reflectivity'][:] 

lon,lat = np.meshgrid(nc_lon,nc_lat) #Unsure if this is necessary. 
#I believe each variable is 1-dimensional
#so I think doing this makes the lat/lon variables into 2-dimensional arrays 
#which is necessary for plotting.

x,y = map(lon,lat) #ERROR OCCURS HERE: TypeError: 'MaskedArray' object is not callable
```

I found a great blog post about plotting NetCDF files using python [here](https://joehamman.com/2013/10/12/plotting-netCDF-data-with-Python/). The author of the post uses the line where my error is occurring to match the lat/lon coordinates of the NetCDF file to the coordinates in the basemap projection. However, when I attempt to do this I get the error `"TypeError: 'MaskedArray' object is not callable"`. I tried converting the masked array to a numpy.ndarray by filling the masked values with "0" but it seems like the numpy array is also not callable. I am also not sure if filling those masked values with "0" would be a good idea, however I wanted to test to see if I could produce an output plot (which I couldn't).

Would anyone know what I may be doing incorrectly? In addition, would anyone be able to provide insight on what command (pcolor, pcolormesh, fcontour?) would allow me to plot the imagery once a solution to this error is found. From what I have been able to gather on the internet, it seems as if the issue could be more related to the NEXRAD NetCDF file itself as opposed to the code posted below.

Any links, knowledge, and/or other help is appreciated. My apologies if this post provides too much and/or not relevant details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a namespace clash. `map` is a Python standard function which takes two functions and runs the output of one function into the input of the other function, thereby gluing them together.

You have reused `map` as a variable name. Change your variable name.